Can bread absorb smells (e.g. when steaming cabbage)?
My grandmother told me she's always used bread (white bread, or bread crumbs) in a pressure cooker to absorb odors from steaming vegetables such as cabbage. I've also seen some websites mentioning using bread (sometimes with lemon and vinegar) to absorb smells when cooking cabbage, without necessarily using a pressure cooker.
Is this an actual thing, or would be it one of those old traditions without any scientific basis? Is bread known as an "odor sponge"? Are there other applications of bread in similar contexts?

How would that actually work? (I don't mean the smell absorbing part) What type of bread? How do you place it in the cooker, so it doesn't become a wet mess immediately? How does it not become a wet mess once it's immersed in steam?

That's the point: the bread does become a wet mess. It's placed in the water. But its sole purpose is to absorb the odor, so it's not a big problem. She probably put some old leftovers, such as stale baguettes, boules, or maybe even some sandwich bread.
